# What's $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=2}^n \log_\frac 13 \left( 1-\frac{2}{k(k+1)}\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I've tried to use the squeeze theorem showing that $\log_\frac 13x$ is ascending for $x<1$ and putting $k$ first $2$ then $n$ and taking the sum but with no use.

Answer (score 3):

Once you changed the log base for commodity, you will notice that:

$$ \sum_{k=2}^{n} \log_{1/3}\left(\frac{(k+2)(k-1)}{k(k+1)}\right) $$

equals:

$$ \sum_{k=2}^{n} \ln\left(\frac{(k+2)(k-1)}{k(k+1)}\right) $$

and:

$$ \ln\left(\prod_{k=2}^{n} \frac{(k+2)(k-1)}{k(k+1)}\right) $$

And here you have a telescopic product. You develop to find that:

$$ S = - \ln{18} $$

Comment: A telescopic product, rather.

Comment: yes, indeed. i'm editing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Guide: Write $${1-{2\over k^2+k}} = {(k-1)(k+2)\over k(k+1)}$$ and use $$\log (a)+\log (b) = \log (ab)$$